# Google Nexus Player DIAL id

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-tv, nexus-player

Does anyone know where I should add the DIAL id ( http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/ ) to my android Apps to be able to launch them on the Nexus Player ?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, DIAL works in that your second screen has a service running while your first screen tells what your second screen should run. After the first screen tells the second screen to launch an application, depending on what the application is, the second screen will open it, assuming the application is available. This will work on the common cases of Youtube and Netflix, but for other applications, they may not exist on your TV. The only time your ID may be involved is in discovery.

If this is for the Nexus Player, I highly suggest you look into [Google Cast](https://developers.google.com/cast/). It's effectively the same as the DIAL protocol. The documentation is much more thorough, there are lots of [samples](https://github.com/googlecast), and integration should be much easier. Depending on your use case, you may not need it. If you just want to see your screen on the TV, the you can mirror it with Cast. If you want users to interact with your application through the TV, then you will have to write your receiver application appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, but I have other apps that rely on DIAL, and since the Nexus Player supports the DIAL protocol, I just need to know how to set the dial integration. Some non-android platforms require it in an xml config file, some android platforms (like amazon fire) have custom parameters to be added to the manifest, but I can't find where to set it for Nexus Player's  apps.